# How to stop html template from escaping

Tags: go, escaping

I have an html template where i want to insert some JavaScript code from outside of template itself. In my template data struct i have created a string field `JS string` and call it with `{{.JS}}`. The problem is that everything in browser is escaped:

newlines are `\n`

`<` and `>` are `\u003c` and `\u003e`

`"` is `\"`

Same symbols inside of a template are fine. If I Print my `JS` field into console it is also fine. I have seen some similar problems solved by using `template.HTML` type instead of `string`. In my case it does not work at all.

**EDIT 1**

The actual context is

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var options = {
        {{.JS}}
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Without more context of where you are inserting your string, we cannot tell which of the `contexts` are executed. See https://godoc.org/html/template#hdr-Contexts

Comment: This is probably what you need to do. https://godoc.org/html/template#hdr-Typed_Strings (AKA read the documentation!).

Comment: @RayfenWindspear I will update my question soon, thanks for your reply

Comment: @RayfenWindspear in this example `<` is escaped as `&lt` which is not my case. `template.HTML` is not working for me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Either change the field's type to [template.JS](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#JS) like so:

```
type Tmpl struct {
    // ...
    JS template.JS
}
```

Or declare a simple function that converts a `string` to the `template.JS` type like so:

```
func toJS(s string) template.JS {
    return template.JS(s)
}
```

And then register the function with the [Funcs](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Funcs) method and use it in your template like so:

```
{{toJS .JS}}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the type of `JS` to `template.JS`:

```
import "html/template"

type x struct {
        JS template.JS
}
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#JS).

Comment: It worked, thank you. But I must choose the @mkmkopriva 's answer since he is 1 minute faster. Still upvoted though